# education system

Tags: customization

i have a project that i need to build, the basic concept of the project is there is a student, teacher management system

1. students and teachers can register on our website
2. students can view subjects offered by teachers
3. student can enlist in course offered by a specific teacher he should have a profile where he can see the details of the course he enrolled and basic stuff
4. same thing for the teacher where he can see how many students he has enrolled

**The most important thing!**

5. payments are done through paypal adaptive payments , in which 10% are sent to the site owner(fixed account of paypal) and 90% goes to the teacher(will be variable depending on the teacher)

i am looking for conceptual help i am willing to buy any theme that meets my requirements, can some one guide me how can i achieve this? even one line help will be appreciated.

Comment: [This question is very broad for a development-centred Q&A site.](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: i am not looking for a detailed answer any  theme or plugin that meets me requirement would be enough, i searched the internet but couldn't find anything that meets my requirements.

Comment: Plugin and theme recommendations are off-topic on this site, though I can tell you that I have not seen anything capable of your requirement #5, and I don't see any way to have a customer/student pay once but have the payment split between two separate accounts. The customer would pay the 10% and then once that was complete they'd pay the 90%, so it would be better to have customers pay a single payment and have the site admin manually pay teachers. In this way you could use a prebuilt LMS.

Comment: @WebElaine Exactly! i haven't seen anything like this i talked to my client so went ahead and agreed for working in CI :) anyways thanks for the help